# Sql query in Python returns nothing

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

I am working on sql queries in python using PyMySQL. Lets say we have the following function

```
def f(bid)
    con=connection()
    cursor=con.cursor
    sql = "select b.text from book b where b.id = 'bid'"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    book_text = cursor.fetchone()
    print (book_text)
```

When I do:

```
f('123abc')
```

It prints:

```
()
```

But If I replace the above sql query with:

```
"select b.text from book b where b.id = '123abc'"
```

It prints the right thing.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure there is `bid` id in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to 'bind' the parameter to the query:

```
sql = "select b.text from book b where b.id = %s"
cursor.execute(sql, (bid, ))
```

**Note**: The benefit of using placeholders (`%s`) in the query and passing an additional object to `execute()` usually handles all different variable types (int, str, dates, ...) for you.

Have a look at the [docs](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute) which objects you can pass to `execute()`.

Answer (score -1):

you '123abc' argument isn't modifying the string you are using for your sql query.
change to:

```
sql = "select b.text from book b where b.id = '{}'".format(bid)
```

Comment: This is terribly open to SQL injection.